# PHP - Reference to Array - how to?

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I want to do something like this:

```
$myArray = array(
'1' => array('2' => array('3' => 'Test'))
);

$changeIt = $myArray['1']['2']['3'];
$changeIt = 'Changed Test';

// $myArray['1']['2']['3'] is now "Changed Test"
```

Are there ways to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
$myArray = array(
'1' => array('2' => array('3' => 'Test'))
);

$myArray['1']['2']['3'] = &$changeIt;//reference
$changeIt = 'Changed Test'; 
echo  $myArray['1']['2']['3']; //Changed Test

$changeIt = 'Another test';
echo $myArray['1']['2']['3']; //Another test
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write $variable = array[key][key]... you  are passing value of the array to the variable. If you want to change value of array itself you need to do it like this:

```
$myArray = array(
'1' => array('2' => array('3' => 'Test'))
);

$myArray['1']['2']['3'] = 'Changed Test';

print_r($myArray);
```

Comment: I know that i can do it this way - but in my problem i have to solve it is not possible to call the array like this and i have to create a reference to change it.

Comment: In that case @Akam answer is the way to go.